# Problems with Dynamic components Angular 12

Tags: angular

i have problems with integration of dynamic components in angular 12, there is a delay when i click on box and when the box appear.

**steps**

click one time on the button Box nothing happen and click an other time on the button Box, a div appear, it's the div when you clicked the first time on the button

---

(and when i click an other time, i have an error "_a.clear() is not a function".) (**checked**)

---

Can you help me ?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uvvafs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the the other answer, kindly referring to that:

```ts
@ViewChildren('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) items!: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

The delay is caused by a race condition, when you call `onChanges`, angular hasn't had time to run change detection, so you are one step behind. You could wrap calling the function inside a `setTimeout`, it would do, or you can manually run change detection after you have inserted/deleted the component. So for that, import `ChangeDetectorRef`, inject it into the constructor and call `detectChanges`:

```ts
constructor(
  public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

addComponent(index: number) {
  if (index === 0) {
    this.Components.push(ResizableDraggableComponent);
  }
  this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Trigger change detection
  this.onChanges();
}
```

Your forked **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e7aks9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fimaginarium%2Fimaginarium.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

It's a type issue. You have `@ViewChildren('container') items!: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;`, but `@ViewChildren` is in fact a `QueryList` of type `ElementRef` in your case.

What you need to do is to tell Angular that you want the `ViewContainerRef` and not the `ElementRef`. To do so, add the `read` parameter:

```
@ViewChildren('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) items!: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

For more details, you can check Angular's [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren).

Comment: thanks i dont have the error anymore. but i still have the delay when i call the component

Comment: I can't see any delay on Stackblitz... @yohanesitruk

Comment: click one time on the button Box nothing happen and click an other time on the button Box, a div appear, it's the div when you clicked the first time on the button